# deleting all the rows keeping only first 10 rows of a table

Tags: oracle

I have an table which consists of 150 records in it and similarly corresponding 150 rows are there but the now I want to keep only first 10 top rows of it and delete the rest remaing rows so overall total 10 rows should be there in that please advise how to achieve this, I am using the oracle as a database.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "first 10 top rows"? Do you have a column whose values define a ranking?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt No , its nothing like that actually i am performing some operation in which I need only 10 records and no more than 10 records

Comment: Define "first top 10 rows". There is no such thing as a "first row" in a relational table.

Comment: can you paste image of your schema, details of fields etc. and also the your work.

Answer (score 10):

You could use a subquery with rowid to identify the records to keep:

```
delete from mytab where rowid not in 
  (select rowid from mytab where rownum < 11);
```

Rownum is an Oracle pseudo-column for numbering rows in your result set - the inner query uses it to limit the result count to 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an column that maintains the no. of rows in the table and frame a SQL statement commanding to delete rows having count no. greater than 10.

Comment: could you please post the query to grasp more that will keep first ten records and delete remaining rows

Comment: see the query posted by Frank Schmitt.